# error in c code: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

Tags: c, function, error-handling, compiler-errors

Program brief overview (3 body problem):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double ax, ay, t;
double dt;
/* other declarations including file output, N and 6 command line arguments */
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int validinput;
  ...
  /* input validation */

  output = fopen("..", "w");
  ...
  /* output validation */

  for(i=0; i<=N; i++)
  {
    t = t + dt;
    vx = ...
    x = ...
    vy = ...
    y = ...
    fprintf(output, "%lf %lf %lf\n", t, x, y);
  }

  fclose (output);

}

/* ext function to find ax, ay at different ranges of x and y */
{ 
  declarations

  if(x < 1)
  {
    ax = ...
  }

  else if(x==1)
  {
    ax = ...
  }
  ...
  else
  {
    ...
  }

  if(y<0)
  {
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

I get an error on the line '{ /* ext function to find ax, ay at different ranges of x and y */' saying `"error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token"`

I think it may be due to not calling or creating the external function in the right way

Comment: Your comment is wrong,
it should be /* ext function ... and ***not*** *\ ext function

Comment: Thanks for downvoting and converting my answer. He posted code with an invalid comment block and reported a _syntax_ error in the exact same line. I'll just think twice before helping people so I shall not interfere with your interpretation of the FAQ.

Answer (score 6):

Your function needs a name!  A block of code outside any function is meaningless in C.

There are, in fact, several syntax/conceptual errors in your example.  Please clean it up and clarify your question - I'll try to answer better when you've done so.

Comment: ok thanks. I'm not sure how far to go in 'clearing it up' because I dont want to paste my whole code down

Comment: Sorry ive never used this site before, how do i indent for code without having to put four spaces in manually?

Comment: @user1170443: select it all and use the `{}` button in the WMD editor widget.

Answer (score 5):

Now, lets take the following example.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world \n");
    return 0;
}

{
    printf("do you see this?!\n");
}
```

If you compile the above program, it will give you the following error

```
$ gcc q.c 
q.c:10:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
$
```

That is because the gcc compiler expects an `identifier` before `{`. So we need to update the above program as follows

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world \n");
    return 0;
}

void function()
{
    printf("do you see this?!\n");
    return;
}
```

It will work fine.

```
$ gcc q.c 
$ ./a.out 
hello world 
$
```

Hope it helps!